# Firing synthetic long press event in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, touch-event, long-press, mobile-chrome

Is it possible to fire a synthetic `long press` event in mobile browsers? Specifically one that will cause the edit menu (`copy`, `cut`, `paste`, etc.) to appear?